# jsoup to listview within fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, jsoup, android-fragmentactivity

I tried to populate my custom list view within the fragments using jsoup with the contents of my friends website, but whenever i open that fragment my app crashes, here are the code that i used
    public class FragmentPoems extends Fragment {

```
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String TITLE = "title";
static String DESCRIPTION = "description";
String url = "http://www.writenepal.com/archives/category/poems";

public FragmentPoems() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poems, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_category);
    textView.setText("Poems");

    new JsoupListView().execute();

    // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
    // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
    // Set the adapter to the ListView
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}


private class JsoupListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Write Nepal");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            // Connect to the Website URL
           /* Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Identify Table Class "worldpopulation"
            for (Element table : doc.select("table[class=worldpopulation]")) {

                // Identify all the table row's(tr)
                for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Identify all the table cell's(td)
                    Elements tds = row.select("td");

                    // Identify all img src's
                    Elements imgSrc = row.select("img[src]");
                    // Get only src from img src
                    String imgSrcStr = imgSrc.attr("src");

                    // Retrive Jsoup Elements
                    // Get the first td
                    map.put("rank", tds.get(0).text());
                    // Get the second td
                    map.put("country", tds.get(1).text());
                    // Get the third td
                    map.put("population", tds.get(2).text());
                    // Get the image src links
                    map.put("flag", imgSrcStr);
                    // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
                    */
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements titles = doc.select("div.span8 h2");
            Elements descriptions = doc.select("div.readmore.archive-inbox  i");

            int l = titles.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("title", titles.get(0).text());
                map.put("description", descriptions.get(1).text());
                arraylist.add(map);
                //String tit=titles.get(i).text();
                //String des=descriptions.get(i).text();
                //data.add(new Contents(tit,des));
            }


            //arraylist.add(map);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
package com.bct071.myapplication;
```

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    //TextView population;


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_show_titles, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_description);
    //population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
   // flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    title.setText(resultp.get(FragmentPoems.TITLE));
    description.setText(resultp.get(FragmentPoems.DESCRIPTION));
    //population.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
    //imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG), flag);
    // Capture ListView item click

    /*
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data rank
            intent.putExtra("rank", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
            // Pass all data country
            intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
            // Pass all data population
            intent.putExtra("population",resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
            // Pass all data flag
            intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    */
    return itemView;
}
```

}

Here is the error i get

```
                                       Process: com.bct071.myapplication, PID: 22075
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.bct071.myapplication.ListViewAdapter.getCount(ListViewAdapter.java:37)
                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:491)
                                                                          at com.bct071.myapplication.FragmentPoems.onCreateView(FragmentPoems.java:62)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

05-28 13:55:37.050 1619-1633/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.bct071.myapplication/.MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

on class ListViewAdapter try to initialize the arraylist..

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=new ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>>();
```

or

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=null;
```

Comment: I tried that,but if i head back to that fragment again, app crashes